# How can I implement database specialization in laravel mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm working on a project that will have two types of **sponsors**, a *person* and an *institution* so I figured that the best way to do that is to implement specialization.
There will be a parent table that is called sponsor and it will has two child tables (person and institution) the two would share main properties that will be in the sponsor table, and they will have their own more specialized properties in their table.
I can't find a way on how to implement that in laravel mysql.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your project, read about a database in order to understand many databases. How to design and download an application called MySQLWorkbench and then draw a daggram in the database Relationships Normalization. There is the third way, N1 + n2 + n3 +
my answer as for your, it create and I find any  call name (Scientific name call table Junk) you associate with a foreign key

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/8.0/en/examples.html

https://launchschool.com/books/sql/read/table_relationships

https://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/